# Is it possible to remotely administer an iPhone from a PC?

Tags: iphone, remote-control, administration

I'm wanting to remotely connect to an iPhone (business, so no jailbroken) and control it.

We have a couple of dozen iPhones, and want to be able to remotely see the screen, and interact with it.

This is possible on Windows Mobile phones, and we're wanting to do it with iPhones.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible without having jailbroken devices...